# How would I go about using a nested loop for distance of two coordinates in a set?

Tags: python, nested-loops

Say I have a set of coordinates and I need to find the longest distance between any points, how would I go about in doing this using nesting?

```
points = [[9, 10],
          [4, 1],
          [75, 23],
          [93, 22],
          [95, 98],
          [99, 59],
          [34, 87],
          [83, 88],
          [65, 42],
          [0, 76]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've done a for loop iterate over the set of coordinates but I don't know how would I go about in doing the difference between any two x coordinate and y coordinate.

Comment: Show us your  current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm rusty in Python, but here is my solution:

```
import math

points = [[9, 10],
      [4, 1],
      [75, 23],
      [93, 22],
      [95, 98],
      [99, 59],
      [34, 87],
      [83, 88],
      [65, 42],
      [0, 76]]

greatestDistance = 0
greatesPoint1 = [0,0]
greatesPoint2 = [0,0]

# Iterate through each coordinate on the list.
for currentPoint in range(len(points)):

    # Measure the distance to each coorditane on the list AFTER the current one, so each distance is only measure once.
    next = currentPoint + 1
    for nextPoint in range(next, len(points)):

        point1 = points[currentPoint]
        point2 = points[nextPoint]

        X1 = point1[0]
        Y1 = point1[1]
        X2 = point2[0]
        Y2 = point2[1]

        # The correct equation for measuring the distance between 2 points. (Can also apply to 3-D space by adding a 'Z' axis to each point and changing this equation accordingly.)
        distance = math.sqrt((X1-X2)**2 + (Y1-Y2)**2) 

        if greatestDistance < distance: 
            greatestDistance = distance
            greatesPoint1 = point1
            greatesPoint2 = point2

# Return greatesDistance.
print("Greatest Distance = " + str(greatestDistance) + " From:" + str(point1) + " To:" + str(point2))
```

Comment: Perfect, took me a while to understand how I would iterate to get all coordinates but your solution demonstrates it really well. Thank you!

Comment: Leetheus, I used scipy, and i got: The greatest distance 133.00375934536586 is between [95, 98] and [4, 1]. Just curious in the difference.

Comment: @oppressionslayer, It seems that both sets of points ([95,98] - [4,1] AND [65,42] - [0,76]) have the same distance. It is understandable that they may be mixed up in either solution. I'd probably round the distances to some decimal point and add code to handle distances that are the same.